# How to load javascript file from another directory

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, directory

My idea is to create a sidebar menu through a javascript file instead of manually, which I already completed. Previously I loaded this JS file from the same directory so obviously the sidebar menu loaded just fine but now, I want to load it from a different directory and it's not just loading even if I have the source just right.

This is more or less the structure of the directories:

js - public_html - leftNav.js

Ofertas - public_html - many html files (leftNav.js previously was here aswell but I moved it)

teste - public_html - many html files (leftNav.js previously was here aswell but I moved it)

HTML file -> offers.html located in Ofertas folder

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
 <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
 <li class="treeview active">
  <a href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Projects</span>
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu" id="leftNav" >             
  </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <script src="../../js/public_html/leftNav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this is the leftNav.js file:

```
window.addEventListener('load', leftNav, false);

var x = location.pathname;
alert(x);

function leftNav() {

 appendUl('leftNav', 'outerUL'); 

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'offers', '/Ofertas/offers.html', 'Offers');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'mobilecarriers', '/Ofertas/mobilecarriers.html', 'Mobile Carriers');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'affilpixeltracking', '/Ofertas/affiliatepixel.html', 'Affiliate Pixel Tracking');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'carrierip', '/Ofertas/carrierip.html', 'Carrier IP');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'updtconverstats', '/Ofertas/Pag1.html', 'Update Conversion Status');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'updtconverstats2', '/Ofertas/Pag4.html', 'Update Conversions Status - S2');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'getconvdata', '/Ofertas/Pag2.html', 'Get Conversions Data'); 

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'getconvdata2', '/Ofertas/Pag6.html', 'Get Conversion Data - S2');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'updtconverspr', '/Ofertas/Pag3.html', 'Update Conversions P/R'); 

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'updtconverpr2', '/Ofertas/Pag5.html', 'Update Conversions P/R - S2');

 appendLiA('outerUL', 'test', '/teste/index.html', 'Test');


function appendUl(append_to_id, ul_id) {

 var ul = document.createElement('ul');
 ul.id = ul_id;

 var appendTo = document.getElementById(append_to_id);
 appendTo.appendChild(ul);
}

function appendLiA(append_to_id, li_id, a_href, a_text, i_class) {

 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = a_href;
 a.textContent = a_text;

 var li = document.createElement('li');
 li.id = li_id;
 li.appendChild(a);

 var appendTo = document.getElementById(append_to_id);
 appendTo.appendChild(li);
 }   
}
```

Comment: Could you try and move at the top of your html?

Comment: @JesperHøjer If I understood you correctly, you're telling me to move my script to the top of the page? I already moved it to the <head> before the <body> tag and also below where all my scripts to load the layout of the page are. I get this error every single time I launch the page: >Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (12:17:06:028 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/js/public_html/leftNav.js
>

Comment: do you have a link to the page i can see?

Comment: @JesperHøjer The page is not online, I am working locally on my laptop.

Comment: In the browser when you access the page, try and press F12 and select "Sources", locate leftNav.js, right click it, and select "Open link in new tab" then you can see what the path for the file is.

Comment: It's trying to open this: http://localhost:8383/js/public_html/leftNav.js which I believe is somewhat correct.

Comment: But did it show your code?

Comment: No, all it says is that "localhost page is not working, localhost didn't send any data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem this whole time was a slighty source innacuracy. On my HTML file I had:

```
<script src="../../js/public_html/leftNav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and supposedly I don't need to have to call public_html in the source even if the program gave the location by itself, so the correction is:

```
<script src="../../js/leftNav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the lightweight http server that NetBeans offers for HTML5 projects, this is not possible. The server can serve only files from Site Root of the project (public_html in your case) but not from outside of site root. You will need to use your own HTTP server instead and configure your projects in NetBeans to use it (in project properties -> Run -> Web Server )